# Unfortunately app has stopped (At first activity)

Tags: java, android, xml, model-view-controller

I've read a lot of threads about this "common" problem developing Android apps.
I've also noticed that it all depends on various problem, some from the manifest, some from Java classes.

I'll paste my code here, please if someone see something weird, please tell me.

As you can see, I'm using the MVC-pattern. Please tell me if you need the Model & Controller java class too.

-----ENTER VIEW JAVA CLASS-----

```
    package kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class EnterView extends Activity {

private Model _model;
private Controller _controller;

public EnterView (Model aModel, Controller aController) {

    _model = aModel;
    _controller = aController;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_view);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.enter_view, menu);
    return true;
}

public void startClicked () {

    TextView s =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    String player1 = (String) s.getText();

    TextView t =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    String player2 = (String) t.getText();

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setId(10);
    int a = b.getId();

    _controller.setNames(player1, player2);
    _controller.buttonClicked(a);


}

 }
```

------XML MANIFEST-------

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name="kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android.EnterView"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android.PlayView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_play_view" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

----------XML activity_enter_view-----------

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".EnterView" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:text="Enter your names below..."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
    android:text="Start Game"
    android:onClick="startClicked"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Player 1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Player 2" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

-----FROM LOGCAT --------

```
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android/kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android.EnterView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android.EnterView; no empty constructor
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class kalle.jack.gui_tictactoe_android.EnterView; no empty constructor
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
05-26 06:33:24.460: E/AndroidRuntime(943):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: @CommonsWare - Ah, I will paste it directly!

Comment: please put controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, activities must have empty constructors. The system cannot call or instantiate your activity if it requires parameters. Remove the parameters or do not define a constructor at all.

Remove:

```
public EnterView (Model aModel, Controller aController) {
    _model = aModel;
    _controller = aController;
}
```

The next error you would encounter would be the `startClicked()` method, as praveenLal said. It should accept a `View` parameter which will represent the clicked button when the method is called.

Comment: Wow, this made the application start! Super thanks, also thanks to praveenLal!

Answer (score 0):

Please use public void startClicked (View v){
........
....
}

instead of public void startClicked ().